# select a value from each row in a list based on an index of column names

Tags: r

I am trying to select an item from each row within a list based on an index of column names (i.e. not just a single column name). 
For example, within the following list "z" I would want to select the values  based on the column name index "ref". So for example, I want the value under column "x" in the first row, the value under column "y" in the second row, the item under column "z" in the third, and so forth.

```
z<-data.frame(replicate(3,runif(6,0,1)))  
cnames<-c("x","y","z")  
colnames(z)<-cnames  
ref<-rep(cnames,2)
```

Can anyone give guidance?

Comment: this doesn't take into account the column name, which is what I am trying to do. The example I gave above was just a simple one. I am not just trying to get the"z[i,i]" values, I am trying to get the values that are associated with the column name within the index "ref".

Comment: `sapply(seq_along(ref), function(i) z[i, match(ref[i], colnames(z))])`

Comment: thank you ... that is perfect.